# Creating a table from a query using a different tablespace (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I want to create some tables in our database from some queries I have developed.  I used the code below and it created the table and it works great.

The issue I am having is apparently it created the table using a different tablespace than the one we are supposed to use.  Is there a way to specify that in code like what is below?  Just a disclaimer, I am more of the end user of the data so I am not as tech savy.

```
CREATE TABLE new_permanent_table
AS
SELECT *
FROM old_temporary_table
WHERE amount<5000;
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Assuming that you have a quota on the other tablespace, you should be able to just add the "TABLESPACE <tablespace name>" statement below your CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_permanent_table
TABLESPACE other_tablespace
AS
SELECT *
FROM old_temporary_table
WHERE amount<5000;
```

Comment: Well that was certainly easy.  Thanks, I had a feeling it was something simple like that!