# ORACLE ORA-00933 when using CREATE as SELECT

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, create-table

I tried to simply create a table with the structure of another table to sync them contents later.
When is use "CREATE as SELECT", it just returns the error
ORA-00933 "SQL command not properly ended"

As mentioned in the link, the syntax should be OK.
https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/create_table2.php
Both tables should be stored in the same user scheme.
The only difference is the added user scheme and tablespace.

```
CREATE TABLE "MYUSER.TABLE_B"
as (SELECT * FROM "MYUSER.TABLE_A")
TABLESPACE "SANDBOX" ;
```

Comment: Ge rid of all those double-quotes.

Comment: Possibly wrong syntax for the placement of tablespace? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620595/creating-a-table-from-a-query-using-a-different-tablespace-oracle-sql

Comment: the double quotes WERE part of the problem, but were used by some generated code in the SQLD assistant. I kept them just in case a query over a dblink to another shema needs them.
TABLESPACE apparently WAS on the wrong position, but i use it at that position when creating new tables and it works fine.
Also thanks for pointing out the other answer, i didnt find it when i was searching SO

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Oracle database with me now, but I am sure, you can use like this-

```
CREATE TABLE "MYUSER.TABLE_B"
TABLESPACE "SANDBOX" 
AS
SELECT *
FROM "MYUSER.TABLE_A";
```